# convert csv to insert sql statements

Tags: insert, csv

I have a CSV file and I want to convert it into a SQL INSERT statements.But I could only find online converters but I would like to know can I create it manually ?

Comment: You can try to bulk load it into a database and export again, this time as `INSERT` statements.  OTOH, why do you need this?  It would be slower on any system I've seen so far, compared to the bulk load options.

Comment: The problem is I cannot insert the CSV file into the table because I am using hana database and importing an array column which cannot be loaded by a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You could open it in Excel then write a concatenate function that builds an insert statement, then copy it down the rows.

But if you really just want to get the data into a table, you could load it using the 'SQL Server Import and Export Wizard', or build an SSIS job to do it.

Comment: Why do you think he's using MS SQL Server? The question is just tagged `sql` (well, Microsoft seems to be quite successful in trying to establish `SQL` as synonym for `SQL Server`)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclosure - I'm its developer). It can convert from CSV, JSON, XML to SQL. The generated SQL contains "insert" statements for each line and a "create table" statement. The "create table"

The app works offline, and your data never leaves your computer.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).

Answer (score -1):

It is better to import the csv file into a table than the insert query
I think background also takes same insert query preparation while importing csv file